# Clever ways to flag EE entries and comments?

Tags: entries, spam

I've got a site with a list of entries on a single page (I'm not using single entry pages) and I'd like an elegant way to let users flag entries on this page without adding a ton of extra code (such as with forms for each entry). Ideally, this method would be able to change the status of the entry to "closed" when a certain number of flags have been reached.

I've reviewed all the modules I can find out there which attempt to do some of these things but they are all designed to add a form to a single entry page rather than a list of entries on one page.

Unfortunately, if I were to use these modules, such as FlagMaster, I would end up with a form on my page for each entry and the code would make the page massively more complex and weighty.

Can anyone suggest how to flag entries in this manner? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What kind of spam do you mean? Comment spam? Registration? Honee pot is an effective way of dealing with it and recaptcha is as well. Definitely lots of ways of fighting it. Even the built blacklist/whitelist addition has been helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Free VZ-average is a framework for for rating and/or tallying.
If you're comfortable with a bit of php coding by yourself,
you can easily make a flagging solution.

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/vz-average